# What's the difference between [nuxtjs3] and [nuxt3]?

Tags: discussion, retag-request, synonym-request

I've noticed that both tags ([nuxtjs3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nuxtjs3) and [nuxt3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nuxt3)) are pretty much the same thing which is the Nuxt framework that's based on Vue.js. I'm not sure which one should be synonymized with the other, but I think [nuxt3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nuxt3) should be a synonym of [nuxtjs3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nuxtjs3), or maybe both should be synonyms of [nuxt.js3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nuxt.js3) (because their parent tags, [nuxt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nuxt) and [nuxtjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nuxtjs), are synonyms of [nuxt.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nuxt.js)). What do you think?

Also, I've recently got the [create tag synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms) privilege. Should I propose tag synonyms without writing a Meta post next time? I was pretty unsure about which one was right.

Comment: "*Should I just propose tag synonyms without writing a Meta post next time? I was quite unsure about which one is right.*" if you're sure or if there's a standardized tagging policy on the site, then feel free to propose it, though it's questionable how effective tag synonymization by voting is since it's not really visible. However, in this case, looks like you don't even have enough tag score to propose a tag synonym.